# Filtering elements while reading .plist array into NSArray

Tags: cocoa, filter, nsarray, plist

First post - hope I'm doing it right!

I have a file, lexicon.plist, containing an array of about 250K words.  I want to load all words of length 'n' into an NSArray.

I know about the NSArray instance method:

- (id)initWithContentsOfFile:(NSString *)aPath

but I don't see any way to intervene in the process of reading the file into the NSArray.  The only solution I can see is to first load the entire lexicon into one NSArray, and then run through it in a loop selecting the elements of length 'n'.

I'm very new at Cocoa, but I have come across some methods that perform some sort of iterative task, that accept a "block" of code that is invoked at each iteration.  I was wondering if such a functional variant of initWithContentsOfFile might exist, or how else I might iteratively read an array from a .plist file and filter the elements I'm interested in.

[And if you're wondering if this might be a case of premature optimization - it is ;-)  But I'd still like to know.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.plist` files are basically XML files so you can use an NSXMLParser on it and filter out the elements of interest.

Comment: Thanks - this looks like the closest thing to what I'm after.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to load a filtered selection of a saved data, you should use a SQL repository using SQLite, for example. 
Plain files can only be fully loaded in memory.

Comment: This will definitely come in handy in the future but comes with a longer learning curve for me at this moment, as compared with NSXMLParser suggested by @Deepak.